# POS integration with Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, integration

My client has an online store that we are building with 10 or so products. They will also have a high street store which sells the exact same products.

Is it possible to integrate Craft Commerce with POS ([Squareup](https://squareup.com/gb) or [iZettle](https://www.izettle.com/gb) ) software so the stock levels are kept up to date?

Comment: This plugin might be useful to import data to Craft: https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally possible. However, since there is no existing plugins for this that is readily available, you'd have to create a custom plugin to do it.

If you have the necessary coding chops, you can get a flying start by generating the boilerplate over at [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/).

If not, you can hire a programmer in the Craft community to do this for you. Posting in the Craft slack channel #jobs should get you started.

Comment: Superb, thanks! I'll get my teeth stuck into creating a plugin.

Comment: Hey @Squideyes, did you manage to integrate Squareup and Craft Commerce? Would be interested to learn how difficult that was!

Comment: @user2315552 not yet. I have an upcoming project which will require the implementation. It's likely that I'll need to build a plugin. Will come back if I go down this path.

Comment: Me too, I will be going down that path with Square POS, let me know if you would like to collaborate and share some of the plugin dev workload :)